# Where can I put my custom task class in Gradle

Tags: gradle

It's easy to write a custom plugin and include it in the build script

```
apply from: "utilities.gradle"
```

For test purpose this file is in the same directory as the build.gradle

Calling a task defined in utilities.gradle from build.gradle works without any hassle.
In utilities gradle is also a plugin defined - configuring it from build.gradle just works.

But if I define a custom task in utilities.gradle calling it is no problem but if I want to use that custom taks in build.gradle it says

```
> Could not find property 'GreetingTask' on root project 'TestGradle'.
```

utilities.gradle:

```
task hello(type: GreetingTask)

class GreetingTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def greet() {
        println 'hello from GreetingTask'
    }
 }
```

build.gradle

```
task hellox(type: GreetingTask)
```

Ok... I read the documentation here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

It says the custom task is not visible outside...
But then... how to share custom tasks with the team without making a Jar for everything.
What I want is to place the utilities.gradle on a network drive and share it with the other.

pls help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a special `$rootDir/buildSrc` directory which is its own build. All classes that this build produces are available to all build scripts in the "main" build. The `buildSrc` build has a default `build.gradle`, but you can add your own. By default, Java classes are expected under `src/main/java`, and Groovy classes under `src/main/groovy`. You can read more about `buildSrc` in the [Gradle User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3abuild_sources).

To share classes across multiple builds, a separate plugin project that publishes a Jar is the way to go.

Comment: Hmmm thanks Peter, I expected this answer but is this approach really practical? Sharing things in buildSrc with subprojects should not be a problem but sharing within a workgroup (multiple builds) only with a Jar seems a bit overcomplicated - but I'll try it.

Comment: OK, I tried gradle-1.6/samples/customPlugin. It was gradle uploadArchives and gradle hello in consumer... not that complicated ;-)

Comment: I'm new to Gradle/groovy, but finding it to be really great to work with (coming from ANT). I have a script that is rather long, so I thought I would use separate scripts and use "apply from:" but I am using custom classes and those were only being found in the script they were in. So I tried this buildSrc for the extra groovy scripts, but now I'm getting "not found" errors for properties in the buildSrc scripts. Any suggestions? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious...